# How to use product of WSO2 correctly?

Tags: wso2

I have already read many documentations of WSO2, there are some products of WSO2 such as: Enterprise Integration (EI), API Management (APIM), Identity Access Management (IS), Analytics Stream Processing (SP). I can understand the functions of IS and SP.
1. But I dont know what are differences between EI and APIM? 
2. When can we use EI? When can we use APIM?
3. Can we merge WSO2 EI and APIM and IS and SP Products to execute all of them on one server?

Sorry for many questions, but I am really confuse in these matters, please give me advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 EI can be used to integrate different systems, orchestrate and then expose as new services/APIs.

WSO2 APIM can be used to manage those services/APIs. You can manage security, rate limiting, CORS, etc. and can see analytics of API usage etc. too. For APIM analytics, there is a customized version of SP which you can download separately.

You can't run all 4 as a single server. Those are 4 runtimes, so you have to start them separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's extremely helpful!